# Unexpected identifier count

Tags: javascript, class, count

I try to count how much ice-creame i will have. i can add and delete icecreame.

```
    class Ice-creame {
    constructor (size) {
        this.size = size;}

        function crCount(){
            let Count = 0;
            crCount.prototype.inc = function () {
                       Count++;};
            crCount.prototype.dec = function () {
                       Count--;};
            crCount.prototype.getValue = function () {
                       return Count};
            }

            let counter = new crCount();
    addToping () {
    {
        this.counter.inc()}
    }
    }
let size1 = new Ice-creame('size1');
small1.addToping();
counter.getValue();
```

for example , i have ice-creame size 1 , after 2 times addToping, getValue must be 2

Comment: is a class name with a `-` even allowed? I dont think so tbh

Comment: there are also syntax problems in this code. try to change `addToping` to the following: `addToping() { this.counter += 1 }`

Comment: and in the vast majority of cases you do not want to affect the `prototype`

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `-` in Javascript variable names such as `Ice-cream`. you need to remove the `-` from it.

And why are you defining a class inside another class and mixing old class definition syntax with the new one !

Your code could be much simpler like this:

```js
class IceCream {
  constructor(size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.crCount = 0;
  }

  addTopping() {
    this.crCount += 1;
  }

  removeTopping() {
    this.crCount -= 1;
  }

  getValue() {
    return this.crCount;
  }
}

const icecream = new IceCream("size1");

icecream.addTopping();
console.log(icecream.getValue());
```

Comment: yep this is much better code. You could also tell something about `prototypes` and why it is mostly a bad practice to affect them.